# Memory profile tool

Tags: .net

I have a web app, that is consuming more memory, which i can see in the process tab from task bar.

I would like to run a memory tool & see which resources are not disposed?

This is a .net,javascript & flex app.

Thanks.

Comment: Development environment/Production or both?

Comment: Is there something i can do by supplying a link, like a fiddler where it monitors if you type a hyperlink in web-window. Since there are modules & i don't have access to all the modules, i have a server link, from which i need to know why the memory grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dotTrace from the maker of ReSharper, JetBrains, is made for this sort of thing.

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Answer (score 2):

[Red Gate ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

Comment: That probably won't help for the Flex part, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since your in Development you can use [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) and attach to the process. Not as easy as others but it is free

Answer (score 0):

I've had much success with [SciTech .NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/). It also displays information about unmanaged resources, which might help with the Flex part. You can attach it to a running .NET process as well.

Comment: +1 : Terrific for .NET apps, good for unmanaged apps.  If you're concerned about memory leaks in the .NET portions of your code and are open to considering commercial tools beyond the one in VS Team Developer, this would be my top recommendation.  It has the simplest configuration and best presentation of results of any memory profiler I've used.